# How to implement follow me function into android dji app

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to implement a simple follow me application for an android device using the DJI SDK for a Phantom 3. I see there is sample code for swift on iOS devices but can't find anything for android. Does anyone have any sample code for the follow me function or know where I could find it? If there isn't anything for the DJI SDK are there examples using ardupilot or dronecode?

I've already implemented the camera application from the dji sdk documentation and would now like to add the follow me application.

EDIT: This is the code I've put together so far. How does it look? If this works, how do I get the follow me mission to stop?

private FollowMeMissionOperator getFollowMeOperator() {
        return DJISDKManager.getInstance().getMissionControl().getFollowMeMissionOperator();
    }
    //create object that tracks location
    LocationTrack highAccuracyLocationTracker = new LocationTrack(this);
    //initialize height to 300f
    private float initHeight = 300f;
    //get initial location of user
    private Location movingObjectLocation = highAccuracyLocationTracker.getLocation();

```
private void followMeStart() {
    //check if status of aircraft is ready to execute
    if (getFollowMeOperator().getCurrentState().toString().equals(FollowMeMissionState.READY_TO_EXECUTE.toString())) {
        //if ready, create new mission that points aircraft in direction of object using the latitude and longitude of user and the initial height.
        FollowMeMission missionOne = new FollowMeMission(FollowMeHeading.TOWARD_FOLLOW_POSITION, movingObjectLocation.getLatitude(), movingObjectLocation.getLongitude(), initHeight);
        //starts the new mission just created
        getFollowMeOperator().startMission(missionOne, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {

                // If there is no error then start the location thread
                if (djiError == null) {

                    Thread locationUpdateThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                                final Location newLocation = highAccuracyLocationTracker.getLocation();

                                getFollowMeOperator().updateFollowingTarget(new LocationCoordinate2D(newLocation.getLatitude(), newLocation.getLongitude()), new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                                        if (djiError != null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getFollowMeOperator().getCurrentState().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // The exception clears the interrupt flag so I'll refresh the flag otherwise the thread keeps running
                                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    locationUpdateThread.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old follow (GPS based) is the easier one to implement.

The mission setup is the same as all other missions:

- Create a mission operator (missionOperator = new FollowMeMissionOperator())
- Create an instance of type FollowMeMission.  The ctor takes a FollowMeHeading, start latitude, start longitude and start altitude. FollowMeHeading controls where the aircraft head points and can be FOWARD_FOLLOW_POSITION or  CONTROLLED_BY_REMOTE_CONTROLLER
- Pass the FollowMeMission to the missionOperator.startMission() you created above.
- If the callback to missionOperator.startMission() is successful then start a thread and pass updated GPS locations as you want to move the aircraft using the missionOperator.updateFollowingTarget(new LocationCoordinate2D(latitude, longitude), callback) method
- To stop following call missionOperator.stopMission()

Hope this helps!

Sample code (I have not included code to read the device's location but the below code will work.

Note: The code does not have complete error handling but is functional.

```
    private FollowMeMissionOperator missionOperator = new FollowMeMissionOperator();

private FollowMeMission followMeInitSettings = new FollowMeMission(FollowMeHeading.TOWARD_FOLLOW_POSITION, locationCoordinate3D.getLatitude(), locationCoordinate3D.getLongitude(), locationCoordinate3D.getAltitude());

missionOperator.startMission(followMeInitSettings, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {

                                if (djiError == null) {

                                        locationUpdateThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {

                                                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                                                    final Location newLocation = highAccuracyLocationTracker.getLocation();

                                                    missionOperator.updateFollowingTarget(new LocationCoordinate2D(newLocation.getLatitude(), newLocation.getLongitude()), new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                                                            if (djiError != null) {
                                                                MyApplication.getGlobalSettings().getDebugLogger().writeLine("Follow.updateTarget failed: " + djiError.getDescription());
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                                    try {
                                                        Thread.sleep(100);
                                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                        // The exception clears the interrupt flag so I'll refresh the flag otherwise the thread keeps running
                                                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                        locationUpdateThread.start();
                                    }
                                }
                        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the start! Unfortunately I'm not sure how to use your advice. I'd like to add it to the existing camera application from the DJI developer website. Do I have to make a new Java Class or can I create the mission operator and instance in the FPVDemoApplication.java file? Sorry for the basic questions but I'm pretty new to all this. Thanks again!

Comment: This is great! I think I may need the code to get the devices location because the line:  final Location newLocation = highAccuracyLocationTracker.getLocation(); comes up with an error because highAccuracyLocationTracker symbol cannot be resolved.

Comment: Many examples online.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer so I get credit

Comment: I marked it as correct but I don't fully understand it. Why do you have the if (djiError != null) and then start a thread? Wouldn't you want to start the thread if djiError = null? When I tried to use this with my drone it just crashes the app.

Comment: Oops, copy/paste error; yes, you would start the thread if there is no error.  I'll fix the code.  Sorry about that

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but whenever I try to execute the follow me mission it just stays in the same place and doesn't move. Do you have any idea what could be wrong? It seems like it gets stuck around these lines of code: getFollowMeOperator().startMission(missionOne, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {

                    if (djiError == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ready and mission Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Hey man, do you know if it's possible to override the active track function to set the distance at 1/2 meter(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I want to be sure I understand what you are asking for as there are 2 types of "follow".

The older one uses GPS coordinates that you send to the aircraft continually and the aircraft tracks toward the coordinates.

The second one is ActiveTrack; this is a visual tracking of a selection person or moving object.  If you are asking about ActiveTrack, there is an example for Android [HERE](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/P4MissionsDemo.html)

Which are you asking about?

Comment: I'm asking about the old follow, which uses GPS coordinates.